# how to create a pandas dataframe from a dictionary with column names as keys and values as rows where the values are 2-d array

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I wanted to know how to create a pandas dataframe from a dictionary.

So about the dictionary d, the size of values of each key is (200, 200),

```
d[key].shape
(200, 200)
```

and there are 59 keys all together. What I want is, the keys should be the column names and for every key as column, d[key][0] can be first row of that column, d[key][1] can be the second row and so on. So in each column, each of its row will have a list of 200 as its values and in total 200 rows.

Can this be done??

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't call your dictionary `dict`, that is reserved keyword.

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame(d)` where `d` is your dictionary

Comment: yeah, I mean my dictionary as dict, next time I will take care. I tried pd.Dataframe(d). Doesn't work. It gives this value error: `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: What are the values of your dictionary? Numpy arrays? Dataframes?

Comment: I have numpy arrays in my dictionary.

Comment: @Riley - `dict` is not a keyword in python, you can't use keywords as variable names in python. It's a builtin's name and those *shouldn't* be shadowed.

Comment: Well actually, I solved the problem and I will mention that in the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering d as the dictionary, with 59 keys (numerically ordered 0-58) and the value of each key is of shape (200,200).

I first created a pandas dataframe of 200 rows and 59 columns. Then later iterated through each value in the dataframe and initialised it with the d[key][row].

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([200,59]),columns=d.keys(),dtype=object)

for i in range(59):
    for j in range(200):
        df[i][j] = d[i][j]
```